# holomorphically convex hull

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a domain. If $K=\{a_j:j\ge 1\}\cup \{a\}\subset U$ where $a_j\longrightarrow a$. How to prove that $$\widehat{K}_U=K$$

$\widehat{K}_U= \{z \in U: |f(z)| \leq \sup_K |f|,  \forall f\in \text{Hol}(U)\}$: holomorphically convex hull of $K$.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The inclusion $K\subset \hat{K}$ is obviously trivial. For the converse inclusion I would try to exihibit a counterexample: let $z\notin K$, then as $K$ is discrete and the limit point is in $U$ the minimal distance between $z$ and $K$ is positive and the set $K$ is bounded. Now using these produce a function (polynomials should work) such that $f$ is greater on $z$ than on the set $K$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is immediately solved by the following version of Runge's theorem:

> Let $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ be a domain and $K\subset U$ a compact subset.   Then the following are equivalent:
>   (i)  $\widehat{K}_U=K$
>   (ii) The open set $U\setminus K$ has no connected component which is relatively compact in $U$.

In your case the set $U\setminus K$ is connected and its closure in $U$  is   $\overline {U\setminus K}^U=U$, which is not compact  so that (ii) is true and Runge then yields the required equality $\widehat{K}_U=K$.

The version of Runge's theorem used above can be found on page 6 of Hörmander's *An Introduction to complex analysis in several variables*, a page which Google generously allows you to access [here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=MaM7AAAAQBAJ&pg=PP6&lpg=PP6&dq=An+Introduction+to+complex+analysis+in+several+variables&source=bl&ots=89FGbThbr9&sig=jEiaF0EyNuH7ogWsjuluaU6KqOU&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1yKqV-fjNAhVCLsAKHaOwA1kQ6AEIdzAL#v=onepage&q=An%20Introduction%20to%20complex%20analysis%20in%20several%20variables&f=false).